# How to match all children using hql

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, hql

What is the best/preferred way to select a (distinct) list of parent entities that has a child collection containing matches for ALL entries in a parameter list of children?

I'm performing the "any" version of my search like this:

```
select p.Id, p.Name from parent p 
where exists(from p.Children c where c in (:childList))
```

However, I'm a little stumped on how best to perform the "all" version of this search. Currently I'm creating hql on the fly for each child that I'm interesting in matching; something like this:

```
select p.Id, p.Name from parent p 
where :child1 in elements(p.Children)
and   :child2 in elements(p.Children)
-- etc...
```

I can't help but think there's a better way to do this; can anyone point me in the right direction?

For reference, I'm using NHibernate 2.1.2

Comment: This seems basically like relational division, but with parameters instead of a table. See http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Comment: @Mauricio: interesting, I have not heard of that terminology before, thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question and I didn't find an easy answer. Simple attempts using "all elements(p.Children) in (:childList)" failed to produce valid SQL. This monster ended up working...

```
var query = session.CreateQuery("select p from Parent p join p.Children c where c in (:childList) group by p.Id, p.Name having count(p) = :childListSize");
var children = new[] {session.Load<Child>(1),session.Load<Child>(2),session.Load<Child>(3)};
query.SetParameterList("childList", children);
query.SetParameter("childListSize", children.Length);
```

Let's break out the HQL...

```
select p from Parent p 
join p.Children c 
where c in (:childList) 
group by p.Id, p.Name 
having count(p) = :childListSize
```

We are creating an inner join with children, which produces multiple rows, selecting those rows that where the child is in the childList, grouping by the parent, and seeing if we got the expected number of rows and only returning those parents. Whew!

Note that you have to explicitly specify all properties in the group by. Otherwise NH only includes the Id and the group by fails.

BTW - I ran this against NH3, though I can't think of any reason it wouldn't work with NH2.1.2.

Comment: Interesting approach - I'll give this a shot and see what the performance numbers look like. Incidentally, specifying properties in the group by isn't a big deal, as I'm already doing that in the select statement (returning a dto rather than a full blown entity)

Comment: This appears to run quite efficiently for my test cases; although it makes you wonder why there isn't some sort of "all in" construct for hql/sql to cover such cases :)

Comment: It would be handy, wouldn't it? When I started digging in, I was surprised that SQL didn't support something like "(list1) in (list2)". I think my technique is general enough that it could be added to HQL. The NHibernate team is always willing to accept a patch. :)

Comment: James, I'd question how "general" it might be...could get fairly complicated with the group by clause; not to mention having to determine the number of children on the fly..one can always wish, though :) I was hoping Diego would put in his $0.02 on this one.

Answer (score 1):

you could query the child and select the parent, as long as the association exists, something like this...

```
select distinct c.Parent.Id, c.Parent.Name from Child c 
where c in (:childList))
```

Comment: This is certainly an option for some of my cases, however not all of my entities have a bidirectional relationship - so this method wouldn't work for those.

Comment: It strikes me as odd to have a domain/mapping the collections are mapped and the corresponding many-to-one properties are not.

Comment: Jaguar; this method also comes with a slight disadvantage, as I'm trying to generalize several searches using a common template; my select statements would differ per search with this method, using James approach this is a non-issue.

Comment: @Jaguar - It's common in my models to have a unidirectional relationship between parent and child. If the object model only requires traversal in one direction, I only include that one.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't this query get you all parents that have any of the children. Take P1->C1 and P2->C1,C2. If you query for all parents having both C1 and C2, you would get both P1 and P2 back. You would still need some sort of group by/having clause to eliminate parents with only a subset of the requested children.

Comment: James, not the "distinct" in his select statement; that would eliminate the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Just using some of logic we can find the answer,
First of all, you had the answer in this query:

```
select p.Id, p.Name from parent p 
where exists(from p.Children c where c in (:childList))
```

The problem here is that here we search about parent having **at least** a child existing in the "childList" list, **but** we need a parent that all their children are in the childList.. but also we know that *the parent which doesn't have **at least** children not existing in childList is the same thing*. So:

```
select p.Id, p.Name from parent p 
where not exists(from p.Children c where c not in (:childList))
```

Optionally, we have the **parent without children** is another problem sometimes according to the situation, So:

```
select p.Id, p.Name from parent p 
where exists elements(p.Children) and not exists(from p.Children c where c not in (:childList))
```